# Reposition some text below a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Stop text being pushed to one side below a span.

The text below "Header" is being aligned with the end of the "Header" text when it should be a new line.

So :

[image]

Should instead be :

[image]

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/72/

Do I need to somehow float right the text bleow the header text ?

Code behind fiddle :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>

.pds-question-top {
font-size:10pt !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-pd-link, .pds-comments {
display:none !important;
}

.pds-box {
width:220px !important;
}

.pds-input-label {
width:85% !important;
}

.PDS_Poll {
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-answer-span {
color:#00f;
}

.pds-vote {
background-color:#424242;
}

.pds-answer-text {
color:#00f;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-answer-feedback {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-votebutton-outer {
text-align:center;
}

.pds-answer-group {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
}

.pds-input-label,.pds-answer-input {
float:left;
}

.pds-view-results,.pds-links {
color:#FFF !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-comments,.pds-return-poll {
color:#FFF !important;
}

.pds-links {
    display: inline !important;
}
.pds-pd-link {
display: none !important;
}
.pds-box {
    width: 220px !important;
}
.pds-input-label{
    width: auto! important;
}
.PDS_Poll{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-question-top {padding:0 !important}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pds-question-inner').prepend('<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 15px;float:left">Header</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span needs the same `line-height` as the paragraph, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/73/